# Redirect in jQuery AJAX using setInterval() (Polling)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have a simple queue system using setInterval() with which I check the queue in the back end using jquery ajax. When certain criteria is met, I want to redirect to a page where the person can continue with the process.

On Firefox I get redirected as I expect, but on IE and Chrome it does not. IE simply gives a "This page can’t be displayed" error and Chrome gives a "This web page has a redirect loop" error.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    StartTheTimer();

    function StartTheTimer(e) {
        var sec = parseInt($("#RefreshSeconds").val()) + 1;

        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            $('#spanQueueCountdown').text(--sec);

            if (sec == 1) {
                $('#spanSeconds').text('second');
            }
            else {
                $('#spanSeconds').text('seconds');
            }

            if (sec == 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Purchase/CheckQueue",
                    data: {
                        applicationSessionId: $("#ApplicationSessionId").val(),
                        eventId: $("#EventId").val(),
                        ordernumber: $("#OrderNumber").val()
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (result.success && jqXHR.status == 200) {
                            if (!result.redirect) {
                                $("#spanQueueNumber").text(result.positionInQueue);

                                StartTheTimer();
                            }
                            else {
                                window.location.replace(result.redirecturl);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('Checking the queue failed.')
                            window.location.href = "/";
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('Error in checking queue.')
                        window.location.href = "/";
                    }

                });
            }

            if ($('#spanQueueNumber').text() == 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                $('#spanQueueCountdown').text(0);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing bracket`}` after `StartTheTimer` method

Comment: updated the script with what I have currently, still not getting redirected

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to my problem, but it is not ideal.

I added a extra div to the page with a link which needs to be followed once the user is in the front of the queue. I am able to - from within the ajax success method - hide the section which explains the process of being in the queue and then show the div with the link to be followed.

However, the requested behaviour was for the page to automatically redirect once the user gets to the front of the queue. So this is a compromise.

If anyone can explain to me why what I was trying to accomplish is impossible, please do so. Otherwise, if there is anyone else out there who knows what I was doing wrong, please do so too. I would love to give the client what he expected.